# Integrated payment system

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a problem, I am currently developing a Hybrid Mobile Application. And I need an integrated payment system to charge my customers. You can help me with a guide or documentation if you want it. Because I had first put a payment system that App store refused and asked me to use an integrated payment system.

Thank you !

Comment: Are you delivering the content or service in the app?  If so, you must use Apple In-App purchase.

Comment: yes I deliver services in my application. now if I use Apple In-app, for Google what should I do ??? there will be no conflict with the apple and Google payment method ??

Comment: You will need to support Google's In-App purchase system on Android

Comment: Thanks I will try!